# How to change java home in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

My machines java version is 1.6 and java home is 1.7 .how to change it to 1.6  using terminal.

Comment: Off topic : see http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-java-home-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "update-java-alternatives" command.  Simply go:

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

which will list your available jdks installed, then simply

```
update-java-alternatives -set [name]
```

to change the java version that you require.