# Java Web Application is not compiling JSPs

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ubuntu, java

I have ubuntu 13.04 and I have installed openjdk-6. On running one of my web applications on tomcat (directly, not using any IDE) and loading any page, I get the following error :

```
8 Jul, 2013 2:32:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:346)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:414)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.arvind.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.arvind.filters.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:935)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:764)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
    ... 31 more
```

I have set the following variables in my ~/.bashrc.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin
```

I added the java alternative for the jdk and set that as the default

```
  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.7                                1047      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java       1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
```

on running `java -version` i get the following

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

on running `javac -version` i get the following

```
javac 1.6.0_27
```

On starting tomcat, it shows that these variables are being used.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/arvind/tomcat1
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/arvind/tomcat1
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/arvind/tomcat1/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix this issue?

Comment: what happens if you type javac -version at the command prompt?

Comment: Can you show us your JSP file?

Comment: @NickJ have edited the question ...

Comment: @PradeepSimha On loading any jsp i get the same error. It doesn't have to do with this particular jsp.

Comment: There maybe compilation error, since you're not using IDE. You may have not got the error. So we need jsp.

Comment: What happens if you type which javac at the command prompt?

Comment: try add /bin at end JAVA_HOME var

Comment: @NickJ - `which javac` gives `/usr/bin/javac`

Comment: @ArvindSridharan, I think there is no problem with environment variables, javac or java. There maybe problem in your JSP, can you add jsp code to your question?

Comment: @PradeepSimha - regardless of the jsp i load i get this error. the error points to java code as mentioned in line `at com.arvind.filters.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)`, also at the end it is said that the cause of the error is the compiler.

Comment: @JIV - most places (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-java-home-in-ubuntu and others) say that the java_home should point to the jdk installation directory only.

Comment: @PradeepSimha - i used an IDE to compile the code. Although there are some errors, at least pages should load.

Comment: @ArvindSridharan, no if there is a errors, then JSP won't load.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the issue. I had to put the tools.jar in my tomcat's lib directory.