# JVM terminated. Exit code=8.. How can i resolve it in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I get this error from eclipse(installed on Ubuntu 13.04):

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=8
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/davide/Scaricati/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/davide/Scaricati/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/davide/Scaricati/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/davide/Scaricati/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/davide/Scaricati/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 730004
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/davide/Scaricati/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

How can i resolve it? .

Comment: Which Java Runtime Environment version are you using? Have you tried using different versions?

Comment: i've got the last java version. I have updated java 2 days ago without problems.. I had eclipse opened and i never closed it. Yesterday i restarted eclipse and i got the error. At this point i think the problem is java.. Right? Do you think it's better try with java 6?

Comment: This is at least what I would try. I tried googling for eclipse's exit code 8 and couldn't find valueable results, yet.

Comment: Yeah me too. Seems i'm the only one with this error.. Wow..

Comment: You are not entirely the only one I guess: http://pastebin.com/3ScQFxDR At least the person that pasted there also uses Linux but I can not interpret anything else from it.

Comment: I think the first thing to try is a downgrade of java.. But from terminal it's not so simple.. Is it a rapid way?

Comment: I thought that you would just download an older version of Java and set the JAVA_HOME path to this version.

Comment: Downloading Java or setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: setting JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-java-home-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

> It is probably because you are using incompatible JVMs. You probably
>   ran an update the settings were changed in the background. This is
>   what worked for me:
>
> 1) Run: sudo update-alternatives --config java

2) Choose a different JVM

[www.anintegratedworld.com/ubuntu-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code8/](http://www.anintegratedworld.com/ubuntu-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code8/)

Comment: the correct syntax is "sudo update-alternatives --config java" thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It should need java files/resources to install

Type

1)java -version

if it shows not found...

then type

2)export PATH=/home/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_111/bin:$PATH

3)java -version

then it displays (java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode))

4)now try installing by typing ./eclipse after going to the path