# Install Netbeans 7.3 with JDK 1.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

My pc has Oracle JDK 1.6_24 and need to install Netbeans 7.3.1. OS is Ubuntu. Since Netbeans asks JDK 1.7, installation of Netbeans cannot be processes. Any possibile thing I can to install  Netbeans ?

EDIT: I can not install JDK 1.7 and need to keep 1.6 version because of another reason. So need to run Netbeans installer on JDK 1.6

Comment: No. Netbeans 7 requires Java 7. Full stop.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't got the NetBeans 7.4 (beta) installer?

Comment: What is the output when you execute `$java -version` in the terminal?

Comment: @AashMaharoon Certainly it isn't the whole output. It should be something like: `java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 4):

Just install Java 7, then install Netbeans 7.3.
When running Netbeans you still chan choose version of JDK and set it to 1.6_24 for your projects.

**EDIT:**
You can install JDK 1.7 in an other folder, you don't have to overwrite your JDK 1.6 folder. For installation just choose the new installation, for programming take your older JDK 1.6_24.

Comment: But already install 1.6 and I need to keep it as it is because of another reason.

Comment: This version of NetBeans is supported with Java 6: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/relnotes.html

Comment: @AashMaharoon Don't matter. You can install it in an other folder, you don't have to overwrite your JDK 1.6 folder.

Comment: then it asks the HOME path .. ? then ?

Comment: then you enter the Java Homepath? For changing your homepath see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-java-home-in-ubuntu