# Ubuntu: change the path from OpenJDK 6 to Oracle JDK 7

Tags: java, classpath, ubuntu-10.04

After downloading the latest .tar file I ran `tar zxvf jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz` to extract java files.

Set the path in `.bashrc` file (`vi ~/.bashrc`) as below;

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45    
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_45
```

Now, running command `java -version` or which java, java PATH still pointing to the older java version (`java version "1.6.0_27"`).

I know default ubuntu takes OpenJDK path. I have to change the path as latest version as my system environment variable set in `.bashrc` file.

Also, `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

```
Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java    1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java    1062      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java          1         manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
```

Answer (score 38):

Ubuntu (and Debian) have an elegant way to manage libraries like the `jdk`.

Using `update-alternatives` you can manage multiple `jdk` libraries on the same system, choosing which one you want to use as the main one.

First you have to install an alternative for the new installed jdk:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac" 1
```

In this way you install the new `jdk` as an alternative to the original one.
Then you can choose which one you wan to use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

You will be asked to choose which jdk you want to use, on my system I have:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

At any time you can see what alternatives you have for `java` or `javac` using the `--list` option:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list java
sudo update-alternatives --list javac
```

To see more options check the `update-alternatives` man page.

Comment: while running sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java" 1
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/javac is already managed by javac.

Comment: @DevendraSingh you have a typo: dont confuse `javac` with `java` you have "/usr/bin/javac" pointing to "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java"

Comment: I still unable to change the path.

Comment: Post, in your question, the output of `update--alternatives --list java`

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working I get  "/usr/bin/java  no such file or directory"  after doing this. Pls help

Answer (score 9):

You probably want to do

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin:$PATH
```

OpenJDK is probably still in the path, and Linux will use the first `java` it finds.

If you don't need it, I would recommend uninstalling OpenJDK.

Answer (score 9):

Run

```
sudo  update-java-alternatives --list
```

to list off all the Java installations on a machine by name and directory, and then run

```
sudo  update-java-alternatives --set [JDK/JRE name e.g. java-8-oracle]
```

to choose which JRE/JDK to use.

If you want to use different JDKs/JREs for each Java task, you can run update-alternatives to configure one java executable at a time; you can run

```
sudo  update-alternatives --config java[Tab]
```

to see the Java commands that can be configured (java, javac, javah, javaws, etc).  And then

```
sudo  update-alternatives --config [javac|java|javadoc|etc.]
```

will associate that Java task/command to a particular JDK/JRE.

You may also need to set JAVA_HOME for some applications: from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22392627/1200764) you can use

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

for JREs, or

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:jre/bin/java::")
```

for JDKs.

Answer (score 6):

Try typing the following in your terminal.

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

The output will be some choices and you can select the correct one which installed to your computer.

Answer (score 5):

Running command in terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

from the command line to set the version of the JRE you want to use as like available version install of java : 1.6 and 1.8 
See below :

[image]

and **choose 1 option and set java-6 version** because already current choice set in java-8.