# Error in `mvn jgitflow:release-finish` mutli-module build (due to wrong compilation order)

Tags: maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use [JGitflow](https://github.com/lukepfarrar/jgitflow) to create a release for my project. Unfortunately, when I run `mvn jgitflow:release-finish`, I get the following error:

```
Unable to find resource 'org.jorlib:jorlib-core:jar:1.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)  
[WARNING] The dependency: org.jorlib:jorlib-core:jar:1.0 can't be resolved but has been found in the reactor.
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. First I ran: `mvn jgitflow:release-start` which reported "Build Successfull". The result looks correct:

```
jkinable@daedalus:~/workspace/javaIDEA/jORLib/jorlib$ git branch -avv
development                07e4c1f [origin/development: ahead 3] updating poms for 1.1-SNAPSHOT development
master                     f3240f9 [origin/master] Updated pom.xml
*release/1.0              f3240f9 Updated pom.xml
```

Next I ran `mvn jgitflow:release-finish` which fails. It seems that it tries to download `jorlib-core-1.0.jar` but that is the file it is supposed to compile. Digging deeper into this, I ran `mvn jgitflow:release-finish -e -X > ~/mygitflow.log`
Here is part of the result:

```
[INFO] Building JORLib - Parent
[INFO]    task-segment: [jgitflow:release-finish] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] org.jorlib:jorlib:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT (selected for null)
[DEBUG] org.jorlib:jorlib-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (selected for null)
[DEBUG]   junit:junit:jar:4.12:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:pom:1.3 for project: null:hamcrest-core:jar:null from the repository.
[DEBUG]     org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test (selected for test)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.jgrapht:jgrapht:pom:0.9.0 for project: null:jgrapht-core:jar:null from the repository.
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for unknown:jgrapht-core
[DEBUG]   org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:jar:0.9.0
[DEBUG]   org.jgrapht:jgrapht-ext:jar:0.9.0
[DEBUG]   org.jgrapht:jgrapht-demo:jar:0.9.0
[DEBUG]   xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.3:test
[DEBUG]   junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[DEBUG]   org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:jar:0.9.0:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:14.0.1 for project: null:guava:bundle:null from the repository.
[DEBUG]   com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:pom:0.9.28 for project: null:logback-classic:jar:null from the repository.
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for unknown:logback-classic
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-core:test-jar:tests:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   janino:janino:jar:2.5.10
[DEBUG]   org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.2
[DEBUG]   javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7
[DEBUG]   com.h2database:h2:jar:1.2.132
[DEBUG]   postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.4-701.jdbc4
[DEBUG]   mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.9
[DEBUG]   org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:6.0.20
[DEBUG]   org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.1
[DEBUG]   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.0.1.v20091125
[DEBUG]   org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.1
[DEBUG]   org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.7.7
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.28:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for unknown:logback-core
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-core:test-jar:tests:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:0.9.28
[DEBUG]   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   janino:janino:jar:2.5.10
[DEBUG]   org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.2
[DEBUG]   javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7
[DEBUG]   com.h2database:h2:jar:1.2.132
[DEBUG]   postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.4-701.jdbc4
[DEBUG]   mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.9
[DEBUG]   org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:6.0.20
[DEBUG]   org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.1
[DEBUG]   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.0.1.v20091125
[DEBUG]   org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.1
[DEBUG]   org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5
[DEBUG]   org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.7.7
[DEBUG]     ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.28:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:pom:1.6.1 for project: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:null from the repository.
[DEBUG] Adding managed dependencies for org.slf4j:slf4j-api
[DEBUG]   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.6.1
[DEBUG]   log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-api:jar:0.7.4
[DEBUG]     org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG]   ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.28:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG]   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG] WARNING: A dependency of the current project (or of one the plugins used in its build) was found in the reactor, 
but had not been built at the time it was requested. It will be resolved from the repository instead.

Current Project: JORLib - Demo
Requested Dependency: org.jorlib:jorlib-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

NOTE: You may need to run this build to the 'compile' lifecycle phase, or farther, in order to build the dependency artifact.
```

The module `jorlib-demo` depends on `jorlib-core`, so it must first compile `jorlib-core` before it compiles `jorlib-demo`. For some reason this doesn't happen. As a result, it searches for `jorlib-core` in some external depository and fails eventually because it couldn't find it.

1. My parent pom: [parent pom](https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/pom.xml)
2. The pom in jorlib-core: [pom jorlib-core](https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/jorlib-core/pom.xml)
3. The pom in jorlib-demo: [pom jorlib-demo](https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/jorlib-demo/pom.xmlhttps://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/jorlib-demo/pom.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this problem is caused by my Maven version. My system runs Java 1.8.0_45 and Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8). At the time of writing, the latter Maven version is shipped by default with the latest Ubuntu LTS (14.04.2) release. I have now upgraded to Apache Maven 3.2.1. After upgrading to Maven 3, I did run into the following error message while executing jgitflow:release-finish:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. 
We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java/bin/java
```

This effectively prohibited the code from being compiled. Notice the weird `bin/java/bin/java` part. I double checked my `$JAVA_HOME` which correctly pointed to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/`. A solution to this issue can be found here: [Having JAVA_HOME inconsistency issue with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776303/having-java-home-inconsistency-issue-with-maven)
I simply created a file called .mavenrc in my home folder which contained: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Now the Jgitflow plugin is working well.