# JAVA_HOME variable gets reset

Tags: ubuntu, global-variables, java-home

I've stumbled upon a maven problem which, according to stackoverflow community, should be a JAVA_HOME issue. So I went to ubuntu terminal and echoed JAVA_HOME. My terminal showed an empty line after the command:

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-DC1B-S:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME

rodrigo@rodrigo-DC1B-S:~$
```

So, after some research, I tried this:
[How to set Oracle's Java as the default Java in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-oracles-java-as-the-default-java-in-ubuntu)

and this:
[Make $JAVA_HOME easily changable in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/make-java-home-easily-changable-in-ubuntu)

which lead me to try the export command. It works, but if I close the terminal and open again the problem comes back. I even changed the /etc/environment to set the JAVA_HOME in the file, like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Again, if a close the terminal and open again and echo $JAVA_HOME the result is the same, the empty line. What is the problema after all ? Why I can't have this variable set ? Oddly, if a echo the PATH variable it works:

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-DC1B-S:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

My java version is:

```
rodrigo@rodrigo-DC1B-S:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set that JAVA_HOME variable in  ~/.profile (this is assuming you are using bash as your $SHELL)

```
vi  ~/.profile
```

add

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

then exit the terminal and start a new one and you'll see that in your session.

```
env | grep JAVA_HOME                
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: thank you ! I will try this if the environment gets unset again.

Answer (score 1):

On Your .bash_profile write the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: After reset, the solution about changing the environment variable in /etc seemed to work. Anyway, thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOs Big Sur

1. add this file `~/.zprofile` if it does not exist `touch ~/.zprofile`
2. add the desired paths, mycase is java and maven.
   run `nano ~/.zprofile` add this.

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven
export M2_HOME
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

3. exit nano and ..
4. reload profile  `source ~/.zprofile`